Inquiry on Testing Chrome's Third-Party Cookie Restriction Policy and Its Impact on AOS/iOS WebView
I am seeking advice on how to test Chrome browser's third-party cookie restriction policy. If anyone has experience or knowledge in this area, could you please share detailed instructions or direct me to resources that provide step-by-step guidance?
Additionally, I would like to know if this policy also poses issues in AOS (Android) and iOS WebView environments.
Any insights or experiences regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.
--
I have attempted to address this issue by using the following method in AOS:
:: CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, false);
However, I was unable to verify if the cookies were being restricted. In Chrome's inspect mode, an exclamation mark appeared, but cookies were still being created.
I am curious about methods to confirm the impact of third-party cookie blocking (3PCD).
--
Thank you in advance for your help.
